# music service stops automatically on backpressed

Tags: android, service, android-music-player, background-music

I had created music player service which stop automatically on back pressed.
I want to set it continuously until songs are available or user manually close from notification window.
Any help appreciated.

Here below i put some code which i had created from reference

```
private MediaPlayer player;
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), 
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() { 
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        //player.stop();
        //player.release();
        return false;
    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //stopForeground(true);
    }
```

Here below code how i am call service from onStart()

```
bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);
```

I also tried by passing in manifest.

```
<service android:name=".MusicService" android:enabled="true" android:process=":remote" />
```

Methods which i'm used in My Activity.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    //start and bind the service when the activity starts
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (playIntent == null) {
            playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constant.ACTION_PLAYER);
            bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        playing = false;
        if (musicConnection != null) {
           // unbindService(musicConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //stopService(playIntent);
        musicSrv = null;
        //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: See your onDestroy() it clearly said that stopForeground(true); so I think the stopForeground method stop your media player.Please verify it.

Comment: I tried by also put on comment but it not stop and when i click again it force close activity.

Comment: Please post stopForegound method.

Comment: this method is for notification dude .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this One....

In service class

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    //player.stop();
    //player.release();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    stopForeground(true);
}
```

And In Your Activity

don't call stopService(playIntent);

```
  @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
    //stopService(playIntent);
    //musicSrv = null;
    //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Comment: Akshay it works but my controls are not displaying on notification window

Comment: Can You post Your Activity

Comment: Akshay now service is not stop work on background but when i close application it makes it force stop how can i solve it ?

Comment: What is the Error it gives?

Comment: And please Share your Whole Activity

Comment: i can not share whole activity i already shared service related methods.

Comment: Akshay it show array index out of bound exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 I'm storing song name in arraylist and that array i'm pass on media player

Comment: for that Refer this link                                                                                           https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

Comment: Akshay i'm also get  java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)

Comment: try  player.prepare();

Comment: rk android Have you check it?

Comment: Sorry for my late replay Akshay it works now thaxs for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the methods `release()` and `stop()` of your `MediaPlayer` outside of `onUnbind()`. When you press the back button, the client (`Activity`) calls its own `onDestroy()` method and unbind the `Service`. If you need to stop the `MediaPlayer` only when the service is stopped, you must move the code to `onDestroy()` of the `Service`:

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    stopForeground(true);
}
```

You have also to remove the method `stopService()` from the `onDestroy()` of your `Activity` if you want to avoid that the `Service` will be killed when you press back and the `Activity` is destroyed. So:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    musicSrv = null;
    //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: it hides notification window what to do now ? i want to control player from notification window also after closing media player.

Comment: @rkandroid So the problem isn't in the `Service` class. Are you calling `stopService()` in some `Activity`?

Comment: @rkandroid You have to remove it. In that way, when you press the back button, the `Service` is destroyed.

Comment: @krandroid Edited the answer

Comment: now service is force stop when i close my application how can i solve it ?